C# MNIST neural network increases to about 20% accuracy, then falls back to 10%
I've been trying to use this python MNIST code to write a neural network in C# - https://www.kaggle.com/code/wwsalmon/simple-mnist-nn-from-scratch-numpy-no-tf-keras/notebook - but after many attempts I can't get it to make significant progress, it seems to always find itself at around 20% accuracy before it falls back down to 10%? Please help.
namespace neuralNetwork3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        string[] trainingData = File.ReadAllLines(@"file path");
        string[] testingData = File.ReadAllLines(@"file path");
        double[,] X_train;
        int m;
        double[,] W1 = new double[10, 784];
        double[] b1 = new double[10];
        double[,] W2 = new double[10, 10];
        double[] b2 = new double[10];

        double[,] Z1;
        double[,] Z2;
        double[,] A1;
        double[,] A2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            X_train = new double[trainingData.Length,784];
            for (int i = 0; i < X_train.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                double[] lineVals = trainingData[i][2..].Split(',').Select(x => double.Parse(x) / 255f).ToArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < X_train.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    X_train[i,j] = lineVals[j];
                }
            }

            m = trainingData.Length;
            Z1 = new double[10, m];
            Z2 = new double[10, m];
            A1 = new double[10, m];
            A2 = new double[10, m];
        }   
        void init_params()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < W1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < W1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    W1[i, j] = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5d;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < b1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                b1[i] = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5d;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < W2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < W2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    W2[i, j] = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5d;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < b1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                b2[i] = rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5d;
            }
        }
        double ReLU(double Z)
        {
            return Math.Max(0, Z);
        }
        double ReLU_deriv(double Z)
        {
            return Z > 0 ? 1:0;
        }
        int[,] one_hot(int[] Y)
        {
            int[,] encoded = new int[10, trainingData.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < encoded.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < encoded.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    encoded[i, j] = Y[j] == i ? 1:0;
                }
            }
            return encoded;
        }
        void backward_prop(int[] Y, double learningRate)
        {
            int[,] oneHotY = one_hot(Y);
            double[,] dZ2 = new double[10, m];
            for (int i = 0; i < dZ2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dZ2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    dZ2[i, j] = 2*(A2[i,j] - oneHotY[i,j]);
                }
            }
            double[,] dW2 = new double[10, 10];
            double[,] dZ2dotA1 = MProduct(dZ2, MTranspose(A1));
            for (int i = 0; i < dW2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dW2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    dW2[i, j] = (double)1 / m * dZ2dotA1[i,j];
                }
            }
            double[] dB2 = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < dB2.Length; i++)
            {
                dB2[i] = (double)1 / m * Enumerable.Range(0, m).Select(x => dZ2[i,x]).Sum();//dZ2[i, j];
            }
            double[,] dZ1 = new double[10, m];
            double[,] W2dotdZ2 = MProduct(MTranspose(W2), dZ2);
            double[,] reluZ1 = new double[Z1.GetLength(0), Z1.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < reluZ1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < reluZ1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    reluZ1[i, j] = ReLU_deriv(Z1[i, j]);
                }
            }
            dZ1 = MProduct(MTranspose(W2), dZ2);
            for (int i = 0; i < dZ1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dZ1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    dZ1[i, j] *= reluZ1[i, j];
                }
            }
            double[,] dW1 = new double[10, 784];
            double[,] dZ1dotX = MProduct(dZ1, X_train);
            for (int i = 0; i < dW1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dW1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    dW1[i, j] = (double)1 / m * dZ1dotX[i, j];
                }
            }
            double[] dB1 = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < dB1.Length; i++)
            {
                dB1[i] = (double)1 / m * Enumerable.Range(0, m).Select(x => dZ1[i, x]).Sum();//dZ1[i, j];
            }

            //update params

            for (int i = 0; i < W1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < W1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    W1[i, j] = W1[i,j] - learningRate * dW1[i,j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < W2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < W2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    W2[i, j] = W2[i, j] - learningRate * dW2[i, j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
            {
                b1[i] = b1[i] - learningRate * dB1[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < b2.Length; i++)
            {
                b2[i] = b2[i] - learningRate * dB2[i];
            }
        }
        void gradientDescent(int[] Y, int iterations)
        {
            init_params();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                updateIteration(i.ToString());
                forward_prop();
                backward_prop(Y,0.01f);
                testAll(i);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
        double[] softmax(double[] Z)
        {
            double[] A = new double[Z.Length];
            double[] exp = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < Z.Length; i++)
            {
                exp[i] = Math.Exp(Z[i] - Z.Max());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Z.Length; i++)
            {
                A[i] = exp[i] / exp.Sum();
            }
            return A;
        }
        void forward_prop()
        {
            double[,] W1dotX = MProduct(W1, MTranspose(X_train));
            for (int i = 0; i < Z1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Z1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Z1[i, j] = W1dotX[i, j] + b1[i];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < A1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < A1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    A1[i, j] = ReLU(Z1[i, j]);
                }
            }
            double[,] W2dotA1 = MProduct(W2, A1);
            for (int i = 0; i < Z2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Z2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Z2[i, j] = W2dotA1[i, j] + b2[i];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Z2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                double[] softZ2 = softmax(Enumerable.Range(0, Z2.GetLength(0)).Select(x => Z2[x, i]).ToArray());
                for (int j = 0; j < Z2.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    A2[i, j] = softZ2[j];
                }
            }
        }
        double[,] MProduct(double[,] M1, double[,] M2)
        {
            double[,] M3 = new double[M1.GetLength(0), M2.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < M1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < M2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    double sum = 0d;
                    for (int k = 0; k < M1.GetLength(1); k++)
                    {
                        sum += M1[i, k] * M2[k, j];
                    }
                    M3[i, j] = sum;
                }
            }
            return M3;
        }
        double[,] MTranspose(double[,] M1)
        {
            double[,] M2 = new double[M1.GetLength(1), M1.GetLength(0)];

            for (int i = 0; i < M1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < M1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    M2[j, i] = M1[i, j];
                }
            }

            return M2;
        }

        private void trainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] Y = new int[trainingData.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Y.Length; i++)
            {
                Y[i] = int.Parse(trainingData[i][0].ToString());
            }
            gradientDescent(Y,250);
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }

        private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int num;
            double[] O = new double[10];
            if (testTextBox.Text == "*")
            {
                testAll(1);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    num = int.Parse(testTextBox.Text);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }
                showImg(testingData[num]);
                O = testExample(testingData[num][2..].Split(',').Select(x => double.Parse(x) / 255f).ToArray());
                MessageBox.Show(String.Join(',', O) + " : " + Array.IndexOf(O, O.Max()));
            }   
        }
        private void testAll(int iteration)
        {
            int num;
            double[] O = new double[10];
            int numCorrect = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < testingData.Length; i++)
            {
                O = testExample(testingData[i][2..].Split(',').Select(x => double.Parse(x) / 255f).ToArray());
                if (Array.IndexOf(O, O.Max()) == int.Parse(testingData[i][0].ToString()))
                {
                    numCorrect++;
                }
            }
            iterationLabel.Text = iteration.ToString() + " : " + ((double)numCorrect / testingData.Length * 100).ToString() + "% correct";
        }
        double[] testExample(double[] example)
        {
            double[] H = new double[10];
            double [] O = new double[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < W1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                double sum = 0f;
                for (int j = 0; j < W1.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sum += W1[i,j] * example[j];
                }
                H[i] = sum + b1[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < W2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                double sum = 0f;
                for (int j = 0; j < W2.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sum += W2[i, j] * H[j]; 
                }
                O[i] = sum + b2[i];
            }
            return O;
        }
        async void showImg(string line)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(trainingData[0]);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(28, 28);
            List<int> pixelBrightnesses = new List<int>();

            pixelBrightnesses = line.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
                {
                    int colour = int.Parse(pixelBrightnesses[j * 28 + i + 1].ToString());
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(colour, colour, colour));
                }
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
        async void updateIteration(string iteration)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(iteration.ToString());
            iterationLabel.Text = "iteration: " + iteration;
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}

I'm using C# windows forms, thanks in advance.
In its current state, it "learns" from around 9% accuracy to 15-20%, before dropping down to 10%, even though the python example I'm using had no problems with this.

I think c# is defaulting to integer instead of floating point which is cause of inaccuracy.  Try dividing by 256.0 instead of 256.

I tried dividing by 256.0d but no change, I was already dividing by 256f though, so I feel like it shouldn't default to an integer.

I would start comparing  Values in python and c# to find out where the differences are.  The calculations should be identical.
